# How do I get selected text in textArea in main controller class from second controller class?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am trying to get the selected text from a textArea in my FXMLDocumentController.java and pass it to a second controller class, HeadingsController.java.

I am running the app in Netbeans and it starts up and loads fine. I get the nullPointerException when I click the Hyperlink with fx:id="h1Link". the null pointerException says its at line 27 of HeadingsController.java which is

```
String selectedText = fxmlDocC.getSelectedTextfromTextArea();
```

FXMLDocumentController.java is where the textArea im trying to reference is...

```
package textareatest1;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;


public class FXMLDocumentController {

    @FXML public TextArea textArea;
    String selectedText = new String();
    @FXML private HeadingsController headingsController = new HeadingsController();

    public String getSelectedTextfromTextArea(){
        selectedText =  textArea.getSelectedText();
        return selectedText;
    }

    public void replaceSelectedText(String string){
        textArea.replaceSelection(string);
    }

    @FXML public void initialize() {
        headingsController.init(this);
        textArea.setWrapText(true);

    }   

}
```

AND here is the FXML file for the above controller...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane fx:id="borderPaneRoot" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="textareatest1.FXMLDocumentController" >
    <top>

    </top>
    <center>
        <TextArea fx:id="textArea" />
    </center>
    <left>
        <GridPane id="gridpaneLeft" fx:id="gridpaneLeft" hgap="10.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="320.0" vgap="10.0" >
            <Accordion fx:id="leftAccordion" prefHeight="250.0" prefWidth="680.0">
                <panes>

                    <TitledPane fx:id="headingsTitlePane" animated="true" text="Headings">
                        <content>

                                <Pane>
                                    <children>
                                        <fx:include fx:id="fxmlheadings" source="FXMLHeadings.fxml"/>
                                    </children>
                                </Pane>
                        </content>
                    </TitledPane>

                </panes>
            </Accordion>
        </GridPane>
    </left>

</BorderPane>
```

Here is my second controller, HeadingsControllerr.java .....

```
package textareatest1;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;


public class HeadingsController {
    @FXML private FXMLDocumentController fxmlDocC;


    String[] headings = {"h1. ","h2. ","h3. ","h4. ","h5. ","h6. "};
    @FXML public Hyperlink h1Link;

    @FXML
    private void handleH1LinkAction(ActionEvent event) {

        String selectedText = fxmlDocC.getSelectedTextfromTextArea();
        System.out.println(selectedText);
//        System.out.println("test");
    }

    public void init(FXMLDocumentController fxmlDocumentController) {
           fxmlDocC = fxmlDocumentController;
    }
}
```

AND here is the FXML file for the HeadingsController.java...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="textareatest1.HeadingsController" fx:id="fxmlheadings">

    <Hyperlink id="links" fx:id="h1Link" text="h1. Biggest heading" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="3.0" onAction="#handleH1LinkAction"  />


</AnchorPane>
```

Here is the stacktrace with the nullPointerException I am getting which I believe is because `fxmlDocC` is `null`... I think I need to create an instance of `FXMLDocumentController` properly?

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink.fire(Hyperlink.java:153)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at textareatest1.HeadingsController.handleH1LinkAction(HeadingsController.java:27)
    ... 66 more
```

I am trying to highlight text in the TextArea through the UI, and have it print in the console when I click the hyperlink with fx:id="h1Link".

Comment: What is on line 27 of your `HeadingsController?` The code you posted only has 26 lines here.

Comment: Line 27 is, `String selectedText = fxmlDocC.getSelectedTextfromTextArea();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is not solved by creating an instance of `FXMLDocumentController`, but by making sure the controller you pass the instance to is the one used with the included fxml; the one you create with `new HeadingsController()` is **not** this instance.

Instead the fact that `FXMLLoader` injects the controller for the included element to a field with the name you get, if you append `Controller` to the `fx:id` of the `<fx:include>` element:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController {

    @FXML public TextArea textArea;
    String selectedText = ""; // why is this field necessary???

    // controller for FXMLHeadings.fxml is automatically injected here
    @FXML private HeadingsController fxmlheadingsController;

    public String getSelectedTextfromTextArea(){
        selectedText =  textArea.getSelectedText();
        return selectedText;
    }

    public void replaceSelectedText(String string){
        textArea.replaceSelection(string);
    }

    @FXML public void initialize() {
        fxmlheadingsController.init(this);
        textArea.setWrapText(true);
    }   

}
```

Comment: Thank you, @fabian. Im kind of getting what you're saying but not sure what to do with the code. Should i be using this line, `@FXML private HeadingsController fxmlheadingsController;` and should I not be using this line, `fxmlheadingsController.init(this);` ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking exactly,but changing your code as shown in my answer should result in the controller created for the included fxml being injected to the `fxmlheadingsController` before `initialize` for the `FXMLDocumentController` instance is called allowing you to pass the instance to the inner controller really used instead just one instance not used with an fxml at all.This should prevent `fxmlDocC` from being `null` in the line you mentioned.That doesn't work,if you load the inner fxml on it's own though.In that case you either need to manually find a controller to submit or...

Comment: Thank you again, @fabian. Ok I have it setup as you stated, now it is giving me another error `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set textareatest3.HeadingsController field textareatest3.FXMLDocumentController.fxmlheadingsController to javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane`

Comment: This sounds like you've changed the `fx:id` of the `<fx:include>` element to `fx:id="fxmlheadingsController"` which shouldn't be done. In that case the root of the included fxml would be injected to a field of the name `fxmlheadingsController` and the controller to `fxmlheadingsControllerController`

Comment: ahhh Sry misunderstood when you said "if you append Controller to the fx:id of the  <fx:include> element", you meant the line, `@FXML private HeadingsController fxmlheadingsController;`. Ok I fixed that and it works. Thank you so much! So the line, `@FXML private HeadingsController fxmlheadingsController;` gives me access to the instance, not a `new HeadingsController()` 
 created by that line. Thanks again, @fabian!